# LocalNotifications iOS 11 swift4 - Works on simulator and not on device

Tags: swift, swift4, ios11, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I have searched similar questions. But i dont understand why this dosent work for me.Please dont mark the question as duplicate.

Local notifications - work perfectly fine both in foreground and background on simulator but cant get them working on device.

AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        print("granted: (\(granted)")
    }

    return true
   }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,      willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    print(" Will Present")
    completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
   }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print( " Did receive" )
    completionHandler()
   }
}
```

ViewController

```
func addNotificationAlert(notificationDate: String , identifier : String){

    let dateString: String =  notificationDate // "20181026 10:55"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HH:mm"
    let formattedDate1: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!

    let notificationTitleMessage    = "Hey this is  ~~~ \(identifier)"
    let notificationsubTitleMessage = "iOS Development is fun"
    let notificationbodyMessage     = "We are learning about iOS Local Notification"
    let notificationIdentifier      = identifier


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        // For iOS 10 and above
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let mutableNotificationcontent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        mutableNotificationcontent.title = notificationTitleMessage
        mutableNotificationcontent.subtitle = notificationsubTitleMessage
        mutableNotificationcontent.body = "notificationbodyMessage"
        mutableNotificationcontent.userInfo = ["key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2"]
        mutableNotificationcontent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.day,.month,.hour,.minute] , from: formattedDate1)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifier, content: mutableNotificationcontent, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            } else {
                // Request was added successfully
                print("Request was added successfully")
            }
        }
    }
    else{

        // For iOS 9
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.fireDate = formattedDate1
        notification.alertBody = notificationbodyMessage
        notification.alertTitle = notificationTitleMessage
        notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
        let dict:NSDictionary = ["key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2"]
        notification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

The "Request was added successfully" shows perfectly in the log.
AppDelegate method - did receive does not trigger in device.

Can anyone let me know if i'm missing something. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the requestAuthorization granted on the device? In the settings? And is the iOS version iOS11 as in the tags of your question?

Comment: I tested your code, It works. Do you set the correct time to trigger in addNotificationAlert method? and please check your device time.

Comment: @HastiRanjkesh Yes, like you can see in the comment beside notification date. and my device os version is 11.4 in specific

Comment: I tested on iOS 11.1.2 and iOS 12.0.1 and it works! I have a button in my viewController when I tap on it call your addNotificationAlert method, and I set trigger timer for next minute like ( let dateString: String =  "20181029 10:07"). and please check your device date.

Comment: My code works. Phew!  it was a device issue. Tested on other devices. Thanks @HastiRanjkesh